# Is this design of a Spring JPA DAO bad or improper?

Tags: spring, jpa, design-patterns

I have been working to generalize the methods of the DAO for a project using Spring, JPA and Hibernate. However, I am still very much learning Spring, Java, and coding in general.

Is the below design bad or perfectly fine? Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have simplified the class:

```
@Repository
public class TestRepository
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<?> getListResults(Class<?> dtoClass, String sqlString)
    {        
        List<?> returnList = null;

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString, dtoClass);

        try
        {
            returnList = (List<?>) query.getResultList(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return returnList;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a concern with the actual implementation ?

Comment: I am concerned if implementing this design would be a bad idea. For instance, passing a class as an argument feels wrong.

Comment: It is true and it should be a no repeated information. Why don't you inspire from Spring repository implementations ?

Comment: What information is repeated? With this design I do not have to create a method for every DTO I want to populate.... This was developed from a basic Spring repository example. Do you have a specific design that I could use as inspiration? Thanks for your help!

Comment: as you invoke getListResults() you pass at each time the class of the entity.  It should be a metadata or passed to the constructor of the class. You can inspire from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository` that is a Spring JPA implementation.

Comment: I understand now. TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data JPA is the must convenient way in order to interact with your databases because it helps you to avoid the common mistakes that occurs when you try to configure your ORM mapping, entityManager, transacctionManager and all the rest of necessary components in order to establish a communication between your entity domains and your database.

For example you have a pojo like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

 @Id
 private Long id;
 ......
}
```

You can create an interface in order to get or put information to the item repository like this:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends from JpaRepository<Item,Long>{}
```

When you need to save the Item just @Autowired the ItemRepository, this is the must important part because the previous interface that is created without methods now exposes ready-to-work methods that will interact with your database, this is the abstraction level that makes Spring Data JPA very useful:

```
@Autowired 
ItemRepository itemRepo

public void createItem(){
  Item item = new Item();
  itemRepo.save(item);

  //or you can get information
  List<Item> itemList = itemRepo.findAll();
}
```

More information in [Spring Data JPA Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: FWIW "JPA Repositories" are not a "standard", and are not part of the JPA API either. They are Spring's way of handling JPA API calls, providing a wrapper over the "standard" API.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Spring Data Repositories?

```
@Repository 
public interface SomethingRepository extends JpaRepository<Something, Long> {
}
```

That way you get lots of methods without having to manually write your SQL query as a string, you retain type safety and you can leverage the power of JPA queries and dynamic proxies that do this whole SQL business for you.